# Does URLClassLoader.addURL(URL) honor the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

Tags: java, manifest.mf, urlclassloader

If I have a jar that includes a Class-Path entry in the `MANIFEST.MF`. If I add the jar to a `URLClassLoader`, are the jars in the `Class-Path` entry also added to the `classloader`? Do I need to introspect the jars that I want to add to the `classloader` to detect this and call `addURL` for each of them (recursively)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does as of JDK 1.6 according to the source code of sun.misc.URLClassPath, but it isn't specified, so take your pick ;-)